# FastClick throws off .on('click') loop count in Phonegap project

Tags: javascript, jquery, fastclick.js

I have the following attached to an href tag:

```
$('body').on('click', '.classidentifier', function(e) 
    {
     DoSomething();
    });
```

The DoSomething() function includes an incrementing loop that's supposed to fire six times:

```
var DoSomething = function() {
    if (ClickCounter < 6) {
    ClickCounter++  
    DoSomethingElse();
    };  
    if (ClickCounter == 6 ){
    BailYouAreDone();
    ClickCounter = 0; }
    }
```

All worked fine in a browser environment with actual mouse clicks. 
It also worked fine in a compiled PhoneGap app.

But I was sick of the 300ms lag that .on('click') events incur in a touchscreen environment, so I installed the FastClick.js library, which monitors for the touchend event and sends a synthetic click to .on('click') events.

But now the DoSomethingElse() function fires > 6 times: sometimes 7, sometimes 8, sometimes more, seemingly dependent on how fast I press the href link. I've tried trapping for ClickCounter > 6 in the DoSomethingElse() routine, but no joy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elsewhere here there is a tip on ensuring that .on('click') events only fire once:

```
$(element).off().on('click', function() {
// function body
});
```

Try that.

Comment: Yeah, tried that... problem was I had several buttons and links on the page bound to the body element: this made them all one-fire only. But thanks!